# Both monitors show as duplicate

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I connected my laptop to an external monitor but it is just duplicating them.
This is how I did the settings for one of them and on the other one is exactly the same except I picked the MobilePC display which means the laptop I think.
Did I pick any wrong settings? When I click on Identify it shows "1" on both screens.

[image]

Comment: What happens after you click "Apply" as per the message at the bottom?

Comment: @Darren nothing. It just duplicates the screens.  Number 1 on both of them

Comment: notice "Make My Main Display" is disabled on both

Comment: I wonder if some proprietary function key is over-riding it. What laptop is it? Do you have any keys that enable projector mode for example?

Comment: hmm not sure, it is a Lenovo T460S

Comment: Found a picture of it, it looks like Fn+F7 might do something.